# Can't plot route with ggmap. route() does not retrieve correct coordinates?

Tags: r, dictionary, routes, coordinates, ggmap

I am trying to plot routes in ggmap, but they fail to appear on map. It seems to me that routes is getting the wrong coordinates. I tried both with geom_leg and geom_path. Here's the example:

```
mainroute2 <- route(from = c("39.951", "-75.173"),  # I tried with point and
               to = c("39.954","-75.195"),            # comma separator
               alternatives = FALSE, structure = "route")

 map2 <- get_map(
    location = c(lon=-75.16662, lat=39.95258), # painfully picked by hand
       source = "google", zoom = 13, maptype = "roadmap")


ggmap(map2) + geom_path(
       aes(x = lon, y = lat ),
       alpha = 3/4, size = 1, color = "black", data = mainroute2
      )
```

I've tried many alternatives and combinations of ggmap, qmap, geom_path, geom_leg. Everything fails. Last week I did it, but now I can't!

Additionaly, when you plot mainroute2 with ggplot (or if you inspect it visually), you see longitude coordinates of 105, which makes no sense since the route should be from "39,951", "-75,173" to "39,954","-75,195".

Please help!

Edit: Problem answered. The coordinates have to be a single collapsed char element, not a vector c(lat, lon). (I also edited my coordinates to point separator and not comma separator, which was also immediately pointed out)

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see 2 problems in your code.

**Prob#1:** `From/to` argument of `route` function should be name or comma separated latitude and longitude.

**Prob#2:** Use of `,` as decimal separator. May be that is not matching with locale settings of your system.

The corrected code:

```
library(ggmap)
mainroute2 <- route(from = "39.951,-75.173",  # lat,lon
                    to = "39.954,-75.195",      
                    alternatives = FALSE, structure = "route")

map2 <- get_map(
  location = c(lon=-75.16662, lat=39.95258), # painfully picked by hand
  source = "google", zoom = 13, maptype = "roadmap")

# color is changed to Red to make it visible clearly 
ggmap(map2) + geom_path(
  aes(x = lon, y = lat ),
  alpha = 3/4, size = 1.5, color = "red", data = mainroute2
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I now see that the main problem was that I was using from/to = c("coordinates"). This didn't work. I used both comma and point separators in the coordinates before, giving them as a vector was the main error!